# UIView in iOS 8 Not Moving up when a UITextFiled Editing Begins

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, ios8

I have written the below Logic for moving a view upwards when a textfiled begins its editing.It is working fine in iOS 7 but it is not working in iOS 8.

Code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  _leagalName.delegate = self;
  _phoneNumber.delegate = self;
  _email.delegate = self;
  _contactName.delegate = self;
  _contactNumber.delegate = self;
  _password.delegate = self;
  _confirmPassword.delegate = self;
}

-(void)animateTextField:(UITextField*)textField up:(BOOL)up
{
  const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed
  int movement = (up ? movementDistance : -movementDistance);
  [UIView beginAnimations: @"animateTextField" context: nil];
  [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
  self.sampleView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.sampleView.frame, 0, movement);
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  if([textField isEqual:_leagalName])
  {
    movementDistance = 0;
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
  }
  else if([textField isEqual:_phoneNumber])
  {
    movementDistance = 0;
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
  }
  else if([textField isEqual:_email])
  {
    movementDistance = -40;
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
  }
  else if([textField isEqual:_contactName])
  {
    movementDistance = -80;
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
  }
  else if([textField isEqual:_contactNumber])
  {
    movementDistance = -110;
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
  }
  else if([textField isEqual:_password])
  {
    movementDistance = -140;
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
  }
  else if([textField isEqual:_confirmPassword])
  {
    movementDistance = -170;
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
  }
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {
    [self animateTextField:textField up:NO];
  }
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
  {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
     return YES;
  }
```

Can anyone please explain how i can move view upwards in iOS 8.

Comment: You have taken the `textField`'s delegate...?

Comment: YES. it is working in iOS 7. i have already set Delegate.

Comment: Are you using Auto-Layout? When using Auto-Layout it is better to move views using constraints instead of frames.

Comment: ok. are the delegate methods called in iOS 8? can you verify that

Comment: No. i am not using AutoLayout..

Comment: @AhmedZ. YES. Delegates are firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in iOS8, it is not recommended to change frame during animation for auto-layout case.
The common method used by most developers would be updating the constrains accordingly in your animation block.

If you still want to try the set frame method, probably you can disable auto-layout and give a try.

Comment: Yes.It 's Working. it is working after resetting the Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following methods for updating you UI

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^ {
    if([super isIpad]){

            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -350, 768, 1024);

    }
    else{
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -275, 320, 568);

        }
}];
}
-(void)keyboardDidhide:(NSNotification *)note
{


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^ {
    if([super isIpad]){

            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);

    }
    else{

            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);

    }
}];
}
```

remember that i am using `[UIWindow sharedWindow]` to draw my nib, you mush be using your screen size and secondly please add following code in your `viewDidLoad` method.

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];`

```
`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidhide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

`